How to print bytes as their char representation in C# the same way OpenSSL does?
I am trying to recreate some of OpenSSL algorithms, and I struggle when it comes to printing the encrypted result for DES encryption.
I know that my encryption is working, since printing the result in hex or base64 gives me the same result as OpenSSL. My issue is when I try to print it the same way as OpenSSL does, simply by I guess printing the byte values as chars.
For example, running this command:
echo "foo bar" | openssl des-cbc -K "0123456789ABCDEF" -iv "0123456789ABCDEF" -provider legacy -provider default | xxd

will give me this result:
00000000: bcbf 295f 49a1 b714 6469 2be2 99c9 0dcb  ..)_I...di+.....

But when running the same command with my program:
echo "foo bar" | ./my_openssl des-cbc -k "0123456789ABCDEF" -v "0123456789ABCDEF" | xxd

I will get this instead:
00000000: efbf bdef bfbd 295f 49ef bfbd efbf bd14  ......)_I.......
00000010: 6469 2bef bfbd efbf bd0d efbf bd         di+..........

As I said, my encryption is working correctly, since when running both with -a flag (which prints the result as a base64 string), I get the same output.
Currently, I am printing my result to the console by doing :
// result is a byte[] that stores my DES-CBC encryption result as bytes
Console.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result));

How is OpenSSL printing its result? Is it a different encoding than the one that the console is using? Is it doing something different? Is it doable with C#?

The 0xefbfbd is the UTF-8 encoding of the replacement character. Your UTF-8 encoding corrupts the ciphertext, apply a binary-to-text encoding like hex (what xxd does) or Base64.

Thanks for the explaination ! I wasn't aware of this replacement character. It is indeed what causes those problems. Do you know how OpenSSL prints its results without it ?

Your OpenSSL command does not perform a charset decoding, but returns a byte sequence. Without xxd, the environment then uses a (presumably environment-dependent) charset encoding (like UTF-8) for decoding, which generally leads to an irreversible corruption of the data (i.e. byte sequences that do not comply with the charset encoding are replaced by the replacement character, s. e.g. here). For arbitrary byte sequences (e.g. in ciphertexts), a binary-to-text encoding (like hex or Base64) should be applied.

The thing is that OpenSSL can print out the ciphertext without it being corrupted by the charset encoding, otherwise you wouldn't be able to pipe two OpenSSL commands in a row like that ?

In the example linked in your last comment, the ciphertext is not decoded anywhere with a charset encoding and is therefore not corrupted. So what is the example supposed to prove?
